# WSO2 Identity Server error ERROR [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

When using a ReadOnlyLDAP as the Primary User Store I saw error [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String; in the logs when trying to authenticate the admin user.

Any fix?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to add `GetAllRolesOfUserEnabled` property to `AuthorizationManager` in `user-mgt.xml`:

```
<AuthorizationManager
        class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager">
        <Property name="AdminRoleManagementPermissions">/permission</Property>
        <Property name="AuthorizationCacheEnabled">true</Property>
        <Property name="GetAllRolesOfUserEnabled">true</Property>
    </AuthorizationManager>
```